# Como suprimir o retorno de curl_init php?

Tags: php, libcurl, resultset

Essa mesma função coloquei numa outra pergunta por outro motivo, nesta pergunta estou querendo suprimir o texto que o $result devolve:

```
...    
$fields = http_build_query($data);
$post = curl_init();

$url = $url . '?' . $fields;
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

$result = curl_exec($post);

curl_close($post);
```

Acontece que o REST no servidor onde não tenho acesso direto, sempre devolve uma mensagem (string) além do true e false, eu precisava suprimir essa mensagem pois ela me atrapalha na construção do html que preciso mostrar ao usuário...

Tentei curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);

Mas não surtiu efeito, estou começando a usar esse curl_init agora

O que eu preciso é simplesmente saber se o $result é true ou false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o `curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1)` para que não seja mostrado o resultado da requisição ou `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1)` se o corpo da resposta for insignificante.

Para saber se a requisição foi bem sucedida, ou não, poderá acrescentar o `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1)` para que o `$result` seja `false` se o HTTP Code for >= 400. Entretanto, o HTTP Code for 300 ele não irá seguir a requisição, acrescente o `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` se houver necessidade.

Para então comparar faça um `$result !== false`:

```
$fields = http_build_query($data);
$post = curl_init();

$url = $url . '?' . $fields;
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);

// Acrescentado:
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1)
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1)
curl_setopt($post, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1)

$result = curl_exec($post);
$info = curl_getinfo($post);
curl_close($post);

if($result !== false){
   echo 'Erro com código de ' . $info['http_code'];
}else{ 
   echo 'Requisição bem sucedida';
}
```

*Estou ignorando possíveis problemas de segurança e não testei o código.*

Comment: Deu certo, valeu